# border-radius is not support in image in Gionee phone, when i am giving the border-radius to image, image get hide

Tags: html, css, android-browser

**border-radius issue in Gionee mobile**

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

but it's not working for me then I try to put an image in a div and then write the CSS for

```
border-radius:5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 6px;
border: 4px solid #ffffff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } 
        .items {
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 6px;
            border: 4px solid #000000;
            width: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        .items img {
            border-top-left-radius: 30px;
            border-top-right-radius: 30px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="items">
        <img src="https://images.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period2/2017/04/15/Photos/Processed/gionee-kqBG--621x414@LiveMint.jpg">
    </div>
```